# Trouble getting started with compass-rails for sprites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I'm trying to start using compass to manage sprites in my Rails project.  Following the "Basic Usage" section of the Compass sprites [tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/), I created sprites.css.scss in my stylesheets directory, with the following lines:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "sprite_icons/*.png";
@include all-sprite_icons-sprites;
```

I also created a directory "sprite_icons" under app/assets/images, and dumped a couple of png files there.  When I try to load a page in my rails app, I get this message:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: compass/utilities/sprites
```

I decided that maybe the compass-rails gem I installed makes that import unnecessary, so I tried removing it, but then I get this error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: sprite_icons/*.png. Load paths: /[...]/app/assets/images
```

I checked permissions on the new directory and they are readable.  It looks like it has the right load path to find my sprite_icons directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I hadn't done anything to tell Rails about the existence of sass-rails or compass-rails.  So, I needed to add the following to (a file required by) config/application.rb:

```
require 'sass-rails'
require 'compass-rails'
```

and now the sprites are generated.

Comment: To which file does one need to add these require statements? Thanks!

Comment: @AnastasiaMelnikova - To config/application.rb, or another file application.rb requires.